# Заполнение массива данными с сервера и отправка клиенту

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть график, взятый из [этого](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/) примера и запущенный на написанным мной Node.js сервере. На данном графике, отображаются определенные значения любого характера по отношению к времени. Как мы видим, у нас есть две оси: `X` и `Y`. В [примере](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/), значения для оси `Y` генерируются рандомно, а для оси `X` используются текущие временные метки:

[image]

А вот как выглядит этот кусок кода:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                // Первая линия
                data: [],                                       
                label: 'Dataset 1',                             
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',               
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',     
                lineTension: 0,                                 
                borderDash: [8, 4]                          
            }, {
                // Вторая линия
                data: [],
                label: 'Dataset 2',
                borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)'
            }, {
                // Третья линия
                data: [],
                label: 'Dataset 3',
                borderColor: 'rgb(54, 102, 235)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(14, 62, 25, 0.5)'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'realtime',
                    realtime: {
                        onRefresh: function(chart) {
                            chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                                dataset.data.push({
                                    x: Date.now(),    // Текущая временная метка
                                    y: Math.random(), // Генерация случайного числа
                                });
                            });
                        },
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как мне самому пополнить эти значения в реальном времени. У меня они хранятся в базе данных. Я понимаю, что я должен сначала запросить эти данные у сервера, сервер должен обратиться к базе данных, для получения этих данных, обработать эти данные и отправить на обработку клиетну. Но как это сделать, я не знаю, а именно:

```
- Как отправить эти данные клиенту
- Каким образом клиент должен получить эти данные
```

Я так понимаю, я должен буду обрабатывать `GET` заявки ?

Comment: то что Вы хотите можно попробовать реализовать на [сокетах](https://medium.com/freecodecamp-russia-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-node-js-%D0%B8-socket-io-eb7498391611)

Comment: `этого примера и запущенный на написанным мной NodeJs сервере`, a точно сервере? примеры вроде клиентские

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Да. Сам сервер я не выкладывал, ибо не было смысла. А тут, я выложил пример клиентского кода. К счастью, я уже разобрался

Comment: примите во вниманее 3 пункта по SSE, в комментах оставил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут эффективней сокетов будут [Server Sent Events](https://learn.javascript.ru/server-sent-events), учитывая что соединения достаточно однонаправленного. [Вот нодовский модуль](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sse) для SSE.
В начале скрипта в соответствии с доками инициализируете SSE-сессию, затем в колбеке `onRefresh` отправляете новые значения в json-объекте. Клиент будет в реалтайме все получать и обрабатывать

Comment: Спасибо большое, это то, что мне нужно

Comment: SSE шикарен, сам использую, но есть 2 момента: 1) соединения молча рвутся, если сеть плохая, надо всё равно делать пинг-понг, и тут уже нужен POST 2) соединений ограниченное количество (ограничение браузера) и на 20 графиков нужен будет мультиплексор.

Comment: 3) для SSE нужет https, т. к. добрые прокси могут его ломать

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov, про 1 и 3 момент я узнал предварительно перед использованием, а вот на счёт того, что соединений ограниченное количество, за это спасибо, не знал ☺️ Нужно будет кое что изменить в моем коде

Answer (score 0):

Если данные раз в секунду и реже, то пойдет GET
(если с высоким fps -- websocket/SSE, но там с обрывом соединения возиться).

На всякий случай в адрес можно время добавлять (чтоб не закэшировалось).

Пример "Pull Model (Polling Based) - Asynchronous":
https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-streaming

Про GET и БД должно быть тут:

https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/basic-routing.html

https://expressjs.com/ru/guide/database-integration.html